# How do I keep a randomly generated image after clicking to next page?

Tags: php, html

I have folder of images. From this folder I make array of images, from which I randomly grab one and display it in the `div`.

Then after clicking on that image, the script should generate another html page with same image and some extra text, etc.

The problem is that after clicking, it will generate randomly grab a different image.

CODE:

```
<?php

  $imglist='';

  $img_folder = "img/";

  mt_srand((double)microtime()*1000);


  $imgs = dir($img_folder);

  )
  while($file = $imgs->read()){
     if(eregi("gif", $file) || eregi("jpg", $file) || eregi("png", $file))
       $imglist .= "$file ";

  }
  closedir($imgs->handle);

  $imglist = explode(" ", $imglist);
  $no = sizeof($imglist)-2;

  $random = mt_rand(0, $no);
  $image = $imglist[$random];

  $rest = substr("$image", 0, -4);
  echo $rest."<br>";        
  $slozka =  $rest."/";

  if ($_GET['run_func'] == 'yes') { 
      myFunction($rest); 
  } else {
      echo '<a href="?run_func=yes"><div id="scores"><img id="obr" src="http://www.etcetcetc.com/'.$img_folder.$image.'" border=0/></div></a><h1 id="nadpis">
text</h1><center><a href="?run_func=yes"><h0><span>stop</span></h0></a></center>'; 
  } 

  function myFunction($rest)  
  { 
      echo '<img id="obr" src="http://www.etcetcetc.com/'."img/".$img_folder.$rest.".jpg".'" border=0/>'; 
  }
?>
```

Comment: `$image = $imglist[$random];` If you need tbe image to be the same after N requests, start a session and store the `$random` value there. The way it is set now, each request runs the PHP code again and the `mt_rand` function generates a new random number.

Answer (score 0):

In your link, just add the randomly generated number as a parameter:

```
if ($_GET['run_func'] == 'yes') { 
    myFunction($rest); 
} else {
    echo '<a href="?run_func=yes&random='.$random.'"><div id="scores"><img id="obr" src="http://www.etcetcetc.com/'.$img_folder.$image.'" border=0/></div></a><h1 id="nadpis">
text</h1><center><a href="?run_func=yes&random='.$random.'"><h0><span>stop</span></h0></a></center>'; 
}
```

then in you other page, use:

```
$random = $_GET['random'];
```

instead of

```
$random = mt_rand(0, $no);
```